# How to get last value of for loop?

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the value of $row->price for the last iteration in my for loop as below

```
foreach ($getprices->result() as $row)
{
    if ($bb=='on'){
        $pric = $row->price+2.50;
        $pri = number_format($pric,2);
    }else{
        $pric = $row->price;
        $pri = number_format($pric,2);
    }
```

I did try the following, however it didn't appear to work

```
$numItems = count($getprices->result());
$i = 0;
foreach($getprices->result() as $row) {
  if(++$i === $numItems) {
    if ($bb=='on'){
        $pric = $row->price+2.50;
        $pri = number_format($pric,2);
    }else{
        $pric = $row->price;
        $pri = number_format($pric,2);
    }
  }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: you mean if there are 10 entries, you want to get the 10th one at the end of the loop?

Comment: Exactly, however the number of entries can vary

Comment: `$rows = $getprices->result(); $rows[count($rows)-1]->price;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$row->price` just after the loop has ended:

```
foreach ($getprices->result() as $row)
{
    // ...
}

$lastprice = $row->price;
```

This is really just a trick, but it will work. If you are iterating over an array you can also do it like this:

```
$array = $getprices->result();
foreach ($array as $row)
{
    // ...
}

$lastprice = end($array)->price; // this will work independently of any loop
```

Comment: OK, the answer I got wasn't what I had anticipated.  Is there a quick way to do the reverse? Get the first in the array?

Comment: Oh, nevermind.  Answered own question, replace end with reset.

Answer (score 1):

Add a line `$lastitem=$row` right after the for statement ; it will contain the last value after the loop is finished

Comment: Why create a new variable when you can just as well use `$row`?

Comment: I suppose its a hangover from languages like C where the loop variable does not have the value it had during the last iteration when it exits, or situations where the control parameter has local scope and doesn't exist once the loop terminates. That has made it a habit for me not to trust a control variable outside of its loop. Agree it is not necessary here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use php [end](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) to get the last value of an array.

eg;

```
$arr = $getprices->result();
$last = end($arr);
```